# How to remove reddish brown boot dye from boots and make them a nice brown

Tags: shoes

I have a pair of leather boots that are this reddish brown color. I would like to strip them and then dye them a darker tan/brown color. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the colour by just painting them as they are - you don't need to strip them of the colour first. But make sure you buy the dye/polish/cream which is made for the type of leather your boots are made of (that is, don't use general purpose leather cream if they are nubuck boots, for example).